# How can I read env variables from command section in YAML file? (in Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes

I echoed all my env variables and they're there, but when I try to read them from command section, **they are empty**.

```
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - >
              if [ ! -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
                echo "KUBERNETES LOG $HOSTNAME - no Admin-user.lock file found yet" >> /data/db/configlog.txt;
                env >> /data/db/configlog.txt;
                while (! mongo --eval "db.adminCommand('ping')"); do sleep 10; echo "KUBERNETES LOG $HOSTNAME - waiting another 10 seconds for mongo to start" >> /data/db/configlog.txt; done;
                touch /data/db/admin-user.lock
                echo "KUBERNETES LOG $HOSTNAME - try create user with user=$MONGODB_CREATE_USER and pass=$MONGODB_CREATE_PASSWORD..." >> /data/db/configlog.txt;
```

Comment: and the classic: It works when I deploy it from my computer, but not when it runs from gitlab-ci

Comment: Are you sure gitlab-ci isn't running a preprocessing step of some kind?

Comment: @coderanger the only processing we're doing is a envsubst before applying the YAMLs.

Comment: Yes, that’s would replace all of your env var refs ...

Comment: anyways, the only thing i'm doing with envsubst is creating new YAML files to be send to K8... How could this affect ? Thank you @coderanger

Comment: Look at the files after envsubst, I bet all of those strings were replaced by “”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203287/discussion-between-wilson-lopez-romero-and-coderanger).

Comment: Hi @WilsonLópezRomero,did below answers help You menage with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for your command or args field.

[Use environment variables to define arguments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments)

> Note: The environment variable appears in parentheses, "$(VAR)". This is required for the variable to be expanded in the command or args field.

```
env:
- name: ARGUMENT
  value: {{ argument_1 }}
args: ["$(ARGUMENT)"]
```

Where {{ argument_1 }} is an environment variable.

Comment: Are we able to do this if we're using "apiVersion: apps/v1beta1" ? (newbies)

Comment: This is true but not the direct answer. The $() syntax is interpolated by the kubelet itself rather than needing to spawn a shell like is being used here. It only works in some situations, but can be handy. (And yes it works with any apiVersion)

Answer (score 0):

refer the below sample

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: env-arg-demo
  labels:
    purpose: env-arg-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: env-arg-demo
    image: debian
    env:
    - name: MESSAGE
      value: "hello world"
    command: ["/bin/echo"]
    args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```